# how to use unit of work pattern in public static

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-of-work

I am Use this code For select 4 Last Record Of Database in various page

```
public static List<Tour> GetLastTour()
{
    using (var Context = new MvcHghDbContext())
    {
        return (Context.Tours.Take(4).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Titl  e).ToList());
    }
}
```

How To Use  unit of work pattern in static Method in Static Class ?
    But Static Constructor Erorr!
    such this code
    plz help me:

```
public static class DropDownList{
    private  readonly ICatHotellService _catHotellService;
    private  readonly ICatTourismService _catTourismService;
    private  readonly ICatTourService _catTourService;
    private  readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    public DropDownList(ICatHotellService CatHotellService, IUnitOfWork ouw, ICatTourService CatTourService, ICatTourismService CatTourismService)
    {
        _uow=ouw;
        _catHotellService = CatHotellService;
        _catTourismService = CatTourismService;
        _catTourService = CatTourService;`
    }
}
```

Comment: Static classes cannot be instantiated and therefore cannot contain a constructor. More info on static classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: @Nakor - Well, not exactly true.. Any class, including static classes can contain static constructors.. but they don't work quite the same way as normal ones..  A static class cannot contain an instance constructor.

Comment: right, I should have been more specific, however a static constructor cannot take parameters so it wouldn't work in the example above

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that this can't work.  Static classes may only have static constructors, and these get called by the runtime when the app is created.  Thus, this happens long before your dependency injection has been configured.  On top of that, you should never ever ever have static data contexts in a web application, because these are shared by all users of your app, thus two users using the same data context will write over each others data model.

Answer (score 1):

- You are not using UoW at all. UoW means injecting one instance of the `MvcHghDbContext` to different classes of your service layer during a request call and not instantiating it directly each time such as your `GetLastTour` method.
- Don't use static classes in your service layer. extract an interface from them and let the IoC container manage its life time.
- Also you can use service locator pattern (such as calling `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<>`) every where even in static classes. It's an anti pattern and should be avoided as much as possible, because now the IoC Container is a dependency in your class.